# Log4Net: Dispose MemoryAppender

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

I'm using a `MemoryAppender` to read log messages in unit tests.

I'm using `BasicConfigurator` in the following way:

```
    class LogVerifier 
    { 
      private MemoryAppender m_appender; 
      public LogVerifier() 
      {
          m_appender = new MemoryAppender(); 
          BasicConfigurator.Configure(m_appender); 
      }

    //other stuff 

    }
```

So objects of this class would be created for each unit test. 
I tried to find if this static class `BasicConfigurator` keeps a reference to m_appender because if it this i want to dispose `m_appender` after each use.

Anyone has any clue on how to achieve this?

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 2):

I have some nUnit tests that do assertions based on events being written to log4net (or not). I use this tear down code and it works well.

```
[TestFixtureTearDown]
protected void TeardownLogging()
{
    if (m_appender != null)
    {
        m_appender.Clear();
        m_appender.Close();
    }
    m_appender = null;

    var appenders = ((log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy) LogManager.GetRepository()).Root as log4net.Core.IAppenderAttachable;
    appenders.RemoveAllAppenders();
}
```